# Issue in Port forwarding in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding, virtualbox-networking

We have installed Oracle Virtual box in Ubuntu 16.04. We are trying to run a virtual machine with NAT enable PORT Forwarding. I am not able to 2-digit ports such as 22 or 88. But forwarding 4-digit ports is working fine.

I want to to host a web server on Oracle VirtualBox. The web server will run on standard port 80. In Oracle VirtualBox machine settings I enabled NAT and port forwarding. When I run `netstat -tunlp` it is not showing port 80 mapping. If I change port 80 to 8001 then it is showing in `netstat -tunlp`'s output. I have found if I use port number less than 1000 for port forwarding it is not working. Kindly help how to fix this.

Port 80 forwarding information:

`r@srv224-asrlr:~$ netstat -tunlp`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address    State  PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939     0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4700      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6023      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN 2771/Xvnc4
```

Port 8080 forwarding information:

`$ netstat -tunlp`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address       Foreign Address     State     PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939       0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22           0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4700         0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6023         0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    -
tcp        0      0 172.17.3.224:8080    0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001         0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    2771/Xvnc4
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.